# How would I write this regular expression url pattern with path in django?

Tags: python, django

I am following a beginner django tutorial and my django version is set up to use path instead of the url and I am unsure how to write this code using path:

```
url(r'^?P<album_id>[0-9]+', views.detail())
```

Comment: Either find an up to date tutorial or for the sake of your tutorial you might want to just use `re_path` which is pretty close if not the same as `url`

Answer (score 0):

Here are docs for path converters https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/#path-converters. In your case it would be

```
path('<int:album_id>', views.detail)
```

Answer (score 0):

from django.urls import path
from . import views

```
path('product/<int:pk>/', views.product),
path('home/', views.dashboard),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).